# does ruby have an elegant way to say array2 = some_lookup_method(array1)

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I have an array `short_code[]` that contains an array of short product identifiers such as `["11111", "2222", "33333"]`

I want to create a copy of the array that contains the corresponding 'long code' data:

```
long_code[i] = my_lookup_long_code(short_code[i])
```

While simple iteration is easy, I'm wondering, as a relative ruby newbie, what is the 'ruby way' to create an array which is a simply method() applied on every element in the original array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) command, which will return a new array with the results of your code block:

```
long_code = short_code.map{ |code| my_lookup_long_code(code) }
```

Comment: This could be written as short_code.map(&method(:my_lookup_long_code)) IIRC.

Comment: @Jorg: Is it reminding you of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962883/how-to-unflatten-a-ruby-array/6963422#6963422 , or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby , or something else?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: All of the above :-)