# Ruby Twitter Array Issue

Tags: ruby, arrays, twitter

I am new to Ruby and had a quick question.

I am trying to get all of the posts from a user's timeline, so I figured I would need to do a user_timeline api call to twitter and then filter out the posts manually. Then, while reading the Ruby Twitter documentation, I found this:

> puts Twitter.user_timeline("twitter_handle").first.text

...and that will return the post already parsed out.

Is there a way to get more than just the first post automatically parsed out like that, or is that just an array method for the first and last object in the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each object.

```
Twitter.user_timeline("twitter_handle").each do |tweet|
    puts tweet.text
end
```

The first and last methods are just convenience methods on arrays.

Comment: @Rob Fixed; oops. (I like that Ben included a doc link, though.)

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like](http://rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/1.7.2/Twitter/Client/Timeline%3auser_timeline) user_timeline just returns an array, so you ought to be able to use Ruby's normal array methods with it.

```
Twitter.user_timeline("twitter_handle").each do |tweet|
    puts tweet
end
```

Comment: Code [golfing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962883/how-to-unflatten-a-ruby-array/6963422#6963422): `Twitter.user_timeline("twitter_handle").each(&method(:puts))`

Comment: but will that work for the tweet text only? how 'bout the more conventional `Twitter.user_timeline("twitter_handle").each{|t| puts t.text}`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/client/timelines.rb), `Twitter::Client#user_timeline` returns array from 20 most recent `Twitter::Status`, so that you can use up to 20 parsed records.