# Is there a more concise way to call an outside method on a map in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, proc

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

```
# Given a directory containing subdirectories: foo, bar
targets = ['./foo', './bar', './free']
targets.map{ |d| Dir.exists? d }
# => [ true, true, false ]
```

I'd love to be able to do something similar to proc calls... it feels cleaner:

```
# targets.map( Dir.exists? )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, possible this way, but not good for performance (see post: [Is the &method(:method_name) idiom bad for perfomance in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby/7169467#7169467)):

```
targets = ['./foo', './bar', './free']
targets.map(&Dir.method(:exists?))
# => [false, false, false]  #all are false,as I don't have such directories.
```

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "point-free"? :)

Comment: This is awesome.  Can you explain the process (no pun intended)?  Fascinating!

Comment: I personally think that the original version reads better (by far). But it's good to have more than one way to do things.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976629/is-the-methodmethod-name-idiom-bad-for-perfomance-in-ruby/7169467#7169467 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962883/how-to-unflatten-a-ruby-array/6963422#6963422

Comment: @Babai: so, you see, in those examples there are no points(dots). But in yours there is one :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Humm.. I did notice.. But here I need to put the point :) Thanks for pointing me to the point.

Comment: Also, it's bad for performance. So it shouldn't be used.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham The link I put in the comment in the answers has the answer,for you.. Please look into those.

Comment: Just did.  Excellent information.  Wish I could up the answer more than once :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev put the same in my answer too. I was going to give that,but got busy to answer you..:)

Comment: I confirmed it's bad for performance in MRI Ruby 2.0.0. It takes twice as long to do it this way.