# Shorthand for passing each item in an enumerable to another method

Tags: ruby

Is there a nicer way to write something like:

```
array.each { |item| method(item) }
```

I'm aware of `array.each(&:method)` which calls the method *on* each item, but is there a similar shorthand for calling a method *with* each item?

Comment: So the receiver is `self` (given in the context) for each element?

Comment: Check https://andrewjgrimm.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/in-ruby-method-passes-you/.

Comment: `array.each(&method(:method))` should work, where `:method` is the name of the method you'd like to invoke and `method` is the [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method (which returns a `Method` object for the given method name) ;-)

Comment: @stefan if you'd like to convert that to an answer, I'd gladly accept and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: @DomChristie I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, so maybe we can close it as a duplicate ...

Comment: Great! I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816654/is-there-a-more-concise-way-to-call-an-outside-method-on-a-map-in-ruby/18816670#18816670 Much easy to search for when you've got the answer! :)